# How to restrict user input to a prespecifed number of words?

Tags: python

My program first asks the user to specify the number of words they wish to enter and then takes them as input. Now I want the program to function correctly and restrict the user if he tries entering more words than previously specifed.

Here is my attempt:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_words = int(input('How many words would you like to turn backwards?  ')) 
    words = []
    for i in range(num_words):
        word = input('please enter string:')
        if len(word.split()) >= 2:
            print('Please only enter one word', end ='')
        else:
            words.append(word)
    print(words)
```

Comment: What is `end=''` supposed to do in `print('Please only enter one word', end ='')`? I have problems to understand what you are asking. Maybe, you can explain the problem with your existing code?

Comment: @Radroad Can you please edit your post and add few inputs and expected outputs...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `while-loop` instead of your `if` statement, so you don't waste an iteration without receiving the right input. For example:

```
for i in range(num_words):
    word = input('pease enter string:')
    while len(word.split()) >= 2:
        word = input('Please only enter one word')
    words.append(word)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_words = 2
    while num_words == 2:
        num_words = int(input('How many words would you like to turn backwords?  '))
        if num_words == 2:
            print('Please only enter one word')


    words = 2
    while words == 2:
        word = input('Enter your string: ')
        words = len(word.split())
        if words == 2:
            print('Please only enter one word')

    print(''.join(sorted(words,revers=True)))
```